# Path Setting on linux server

Tags: apache-httpd, php

I have php project that is running perfectly on window .

now I am deploying project on Centos Linux Server .

```
define('INCLUDES_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'cms-includes/');
ini_set('include_path',INCLUDES_PATH.':'.ini_get('include_path'));
```

so `INCLUDES_PATH` --> `C:\xampp\htdocs\cms-includes`

I am facing one path issue on Linux. In Linux my project location is `/var/www/web_loan/xampp/htdocs\...cms-includes`

Now there is the issue of setting path for `C:\`. How can I do that in Linux because there is no `C:\` location on the server.

what type of path I should give?

The error looks like this

```
Fatal error in line 15 of file/var/www/web_loan/xampp/htdocs/cms-includes/init.inc.php
- require_once(INCLUDES_PATHpear.mysql.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'INCLUDES_PATHpear.mysql.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/web_loan/xampp/htdocs/cms-includes/init.inc.php on line 15.
```

LINE # 15 looks like in `init.inc.php`

```
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH . 'pear.mysql.php');
```

Should I define INCLUDES_PATH according to Linux in `defines.inc.php`?

Comment: Please don't tag with distribution names unless your question is *specific* to that distribution. Also, please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format code as `code`. Your question is very hard to understand at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, verify that the file is there. On the command prompt type:

```
ls -l /var/www/web_loan/xampp/htdocs/cms-includes/init.inc.php
```

this should also show you the ownership of the file. Make sure that the user running apache can read this file. Typically that user is `www-data`. If not, run this:

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/web_loan/xampp/htdocs/cms-includes/init.inc.php
```

Try giving the absolute path in your `require` statement:

```
require_once('/var/www/web_loan/xampp/htdocs/cms-includes/pear.mysql.php');
```

If this is working, it could be the constant variable is not getting defined properly .

EDIT: chown not chmod

Comment: when i run first command(1s -1) it gives me -rwxrwxrwx 1 root apache 3979 Sep 27 07:44 /var/www/web_loan/xampp/htdocs/cms-includes/init.inc.php

Comment: and for second it gives me chmod :invalid mod: 'www-data:www-data'

Comment: fixed my error by using absolute path ...but INCLUDES_PATH used in many places in project , how can i set it in file defines.inc.php .                           define('INCLUDES_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'cms-includes/');

Comment: you need to debug the INCLUDES_PATH constant. run, <?php echo constant("INCLUDE_PATH"); ?> and see what the out put of INCLUDE_PATH is, and what ROOT_PATH is, and see if that lines up with the absolute path. If it does not find out where these constants are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Drive letters such as `C:`, `D:` etc. don't exist under Unix/Linux. Whatever file there is, you will find it somewhere under `/`. Note that the directory separator under Unix/Linux is `/`, not `\`.

Given what you wrote, replace `C:\` by `/var/www/web_loan` and replace all back-slashes (`\`) by forward-slashes (`/`)

Comment: you are right i have did as you said . but when i change in file defines.inc.php . and run my project , that say to me  fatal error - includes_path undefined constant .